# Tomcat output not appearing in console view

Tags: eclipse-wtp, eclipse-kepler

Have recently upgraded eclipse from Juno to Kepler, and now when I start a tomcat 7 server using WTP (by selecting the server in the 'Servers' view and pressing the run button in the view's button bar) the console view pops up to the front like before, but instead of displaying tomcat's output like it did in Juno it just displays a message that reads "No consoles to display at this time."

I have tried checking the server launch configuration (double click on server entry in Servers view, click 'Open launch configuration' link, switch to 'Common' tab) but the checkbox 'Allocate console' is ticked, which is the only control I am aware of that could cause this problem.

Any suggestions how I get the console back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `<tomcat folder>/conf/logging.properties` and make sure that debug level is still set to  "info", then go to `../logs` folder and delete all the logs. Shut Eclipse down, check in task manager that both Eclipse and Tomcat are totally down and then restart Eclipse and try again.

Comment: Just shutting down Eclipse then restarting was all I needed.  Thanks alfasin.

Comment: @user903724 I wrote all these steps of remediation - usually one of them treats the issue - glad it worked for you as well :)

Comment: In my case they are already al set to INFO, there are no logs in ../logs.  But stdout still does not show in the console.